# Find partition in file backup on OSX

Tags: macos, partitioning

I have a file which contains some kind of filesystem or partitions on it. I would like to find partitions in the file. I have read a great article on this topic here: [Mounting a hard disk image including partitions using Linux](http://www.andremiller.net/content/mounting-hard-disk-image-including-partitions-using-linux)

Is there any software which do the same like *parted* on OSX?

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify the format of the disk image file, but OS X has shipped with [Disk Utility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_Utility) since 10.3 and it provides both a GUI application and matching command line tools (diskutil and hdiutil).

Comment: The problrm is that I don't really know the filesystem. There is a big chance that it is ext3, but it isn't simply mounting because it might contain multiple partitions.